# Display 2d vector/2d array into simple figure in c++ Qt

Tags: c++, qt, figure, qimage, 2d-vector

I have to compare two 2d vectors (`vect_2d_a` and `vect_2d_b`) and as a result I will construct a 2d vector/2d array (`vect_compare_result`) comprising the difference in value of `vect_2d_a` and `vect_2d_b`.

Basically I can simply print the `vect_compare_result` and view it, but I would like to see it as a figure with simple  boxes indicating the difference value in pixels (like colorbar in matlab).

Is it possible  to display a simple 2d vector into a figure using `Qimg` or something?

Priya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that size of your vector is `n x n`:

```
QImage image(n, n, QImage::Format_RGB32);
QRgb value;

for (int i=0;i<N;++i) {
    for (int j=0;j<N;++j) {
        value = getColor(vect_compare_result); //a function that returns color based on value
        image.setPixel(i, j, value);
    }
}
```

If you want your pixels to be bigger (like one box is 5x5 real pixels):

```
int box_size = 5;
QImage image(n * box_size, n * box_size, QImage::Format_RGB32);
QRgb value;

for (int i=0;i<N;++i) {
    for (int j=0;j<N;++j) {
        value = getColor(vect_compare_result);
        for (int k=0;k<box_size;++k)
            for (int l=0;l<box_size;++l)
                image.setPixel(i+k, j+l, value);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am using Qt creator for the first time. When i try to #include <QImage>, it says no such file or directory. I would like to know whether i need to download any package or change any settings in order to work with QImg.

Comment: I don't know, it's too few information. If you installed QtCreator with all the libraries it should be there. Maybe you need to set some paths in your system.

Comment: Do not use `setPixel`, it's slow. Access pixel data directly.